# Using too many 'to's in a sentence?

Tags: grammar, prepositions, adverbs, infinitives

This may be more of a stylistic question than anything else, but I'm hoping for some general rules about using the word 'to' in a sentence and when it might be used too many times.

For example, I'm not sure there's anything wrong with the following sentence from a grammar / structure standpoint:

> We are pleased to update you with our progress and to propose a new
>   idea to speed up our product launch into the market to generate
>   revenue.

I find this sentence irritating but I'm not sure exactly why outside of just "wordiness" - but that's normally a good marker (for me) that there's a mistake.

So my question is three part:

1. Is the above sentence grammatically sound but just in need of word-crafting?
2. What is it about the sentence that I'm finding troublesome?
3. Are there any rules that one can remember to identify and avoid this mistake, if it is in fact a mistake?

Thanks in advance and best.

Comment: Even if we throw out all the preceding text, *[**We want**] to speed up our product launch into the market to generate revenue* sounds pretty clumsy to me. It's also *semantically* questionable in context. Who exactly will be *receiving* the generated revenue? More crucially, who will be *paying?* Your text looks like a flyer to actual/potential *customers*, who might not particularly want to be told how pleased you are that you've thought of new and better ways of getting their money.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - that's an excellent point. Taken "as is" without all of the implied language and the sentence is actually semantically problematic.

Answer (score 3):

1. Grammatically sound? Yes.
2. What's troublesome? Just a bit ungainly.
3. No actual mistakes.

Suggested rewording [words in square brackets are superfluous]:

"We are pleased to update you **on** our progress**,** and **also** propose **an** [new] idea **that would** speed up our product launch [into the market] **and** generate revenue.

- Add comma after "progress" to break up the long sentence.
- Does "new" add anything to "idea"?
- Where would you launch the product if not "into the market"?
- Could change "speed up" to "accelerate"

Comment: Thank you for your feedback and will likely take you up on the rewording suggestions. If you look at FumbleFingers comment - I suspect it's correct and that semantics is *actually a problem* or maybe even a "mistake." I would greatly appreciate your feedback on that point.

Comment: You could write "product launch **in order to** generate revenue".  Beyond that, I agree with FF's comments, but without knowing who you are addressing the message to - whether investors or customers - nor what your 'new idea' is, I don't feel I can comment further.

Comment: Great answer, upvoted. But how does it sound weird to say " We are pleased to update you with our progress ". I saw no problem there and felt nothing about how it sounds. Could you explain the subtle difference between " with our progress " vs " on our progress " ?

Comment: Looking at the definition of "with" (British Eng.) at https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/with, in very general terms "with" generally implies 'togetherness': that two (or more) things are brought or used ot happening **together**.  But in the sentence in question, there is no 'togetherness': information is being passed from - or transferred from - one person/company to another person/company.  I agree that 'with' ***could*** be used in the sentence in question, but to my British ears it doesn't sound quite right.  Hope that helps.